# Comparing two Python dicts: CS50 PSET6 DNA

Tags: python, dictionary, cs50

Need some help comparing two dicts in Python.

I'd like to see if all the key:value pairs in **result_dict** match any of the corresponding key:value pairs in **database_dict**. How do I iterate over the different **result_dict.keys** to check if the corresponding value matches with that in **database_dict**? And if there is a complete match then return 'name'. Thanks for your help. Dicts below:

result_dict:

```
{'AGATC': 4, 'AATG': 1, 'TATC': 5}
```

database_dict:

```
OrderedDict([('name', 'Alice'), ('AGATC', '2'), ('AATG', '8'), ('TATC', '3')])  
OrderedDict([('name', 'Bob'), ('AGATC', '4'), ('AATG', '1'), ('TATC', '5')])  
OrderedDict([('name', 'Charlie'), ('AGATC', '3'), ('AATG', '2'), ('TATC', '5')])
```

Comment: What is a 'complete' match? All of the result_dict keys are in the database_dict?

Comment: What have you tried before you asked us? Can you please share the code you have at the moment?

Answer (score 0):

The following function returns the names of the people who match the result_dict. It removes the name value using pop and converts the scores to ints to allow comparison with result_dict.

```
database_dicts = [OrderedDict([('name', 'Alice'), ('AGATC', '2'), ('AATG', '8'), ('TATC', '3')]),
OrderedDict([('name', 'Bob'), ('AGATC', '4'), ('AATG', '1'), ('TATC', '5')]),
OrderedDict([('name', 'Charlie'), ('AGATC', '3'), ('AATG', '2'), ('TATC', '5')])]

result_dict = {'AGATC': 4, 'AATG': 1, 'TATC': 5}

def get_name(database_dicts, result_dict):
    names = []
    for dd in database_dicts:
        name = dd['name']
        dd.pop('name')
        dd = {key: int(value) for key, value in dd.items()}
        if dd == result_dict:
            names.append(name)
    return names

names = get_name(database_dicts, result_dict)
print(names)
```